# How do I select and highlight a UICollectionView like a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, highlight

I have a simple dilemma. I have a UICollectionViewController in my app that displays saved quizzes. I have the loading right, but I want it to move detect a tap on one of them and then do logic to load it into the main VC. I would like the selection to be similar to a UITableViewCell where it highlights it for a second and then unhighlights it. I am using a subclassed UICollectionViewCell if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for the highlighting to show, you can subclass your cells like this:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)

        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        self.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
    }
}
```

From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewCell/selectedBackgroundView) for `UICollectionViewCell`:

> You can use this view to give the cell a custom appearance when it is
>   selected. When the cell is selected, this view is layered above the
>   backgroundView and behind the contentView.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering what those outlets were. And thanks for a code example.

Comment: There was a mistake in my original answer (assigning a `UIColor` value to a `UIView` property). Somebody suggested a correct fix but seems to have been rejected. I have edited the answer to fix it.

Comment: This answer does not seem to work any more in Xcode 12.2 on Big Sur 11.1 targeting iOS 14.0. I get "Instance member 'selectedBackgroundView' cannot be used on type 'My_CollectionViewCell'".

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionViewCell has a property

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isHighlighted) BOOL highlighted;
```

You can use this property for selecting the UICollectionViewCell in cellForItemAtIndexPath:

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm new to UICollectionViews and had 10 trys just to get the cells working

Comment: Can you let me know whats the criteria for you to highlight the cell (User selected item ?). So i can post a answer in more detail way.

Comment: Just like selecting a (default) uitableviewcell. It turns blue for a moment and becomes normal. Also selecting it similar to a button would be cool too. (You know, with the shadow color and stuff)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike UITableView, in UICollectionView there is no specific method defined to do so. U need to implement it programmatically by changing its background colour or background image of the specific cell for instant.
U can refer Apple Documentation.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/
Hope it helps.

*****EDITED*****
You can refer this ans too..
[Why UICollectionView's UICollectionViewCell is not highlighting on user touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637031/why-uicollectionviews-uicollectionviewcell-is-not-highlighting-on-user-touch)
Happy Coding.. :)