# highlighting uicollectionview cell on tap

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a slide-out menu that I have implemented as a UICollectionViewController. I have created custom cells for the collection view as well. The navigation and everything works as expected. What I am having trouble with is changing the cells appearance when I click on an actual cell.

I've tried several approaches based on solutions([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392485/change-background-of-uicollectionview-cell-on-tap))([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637031/why-uicollectionviews-uicollectionviewcell-is-not-highlighting-on-user-touch)) I've seen here on stack but nothing to my satisfaction.

**Solution 1**: implement the UICollectionViewController delegate methods:

```
class SlideOutMenuViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
   //Setup code and other delegate methods….

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! SlideOutMenuCells

        cell.backgroundColor = .white
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! SlideOutMenuCells

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.mainGreen()
    }
}
```

When I tried this solution, nothing happens. The cells background color doesn't change colors.

**Solution 2**: This solution results in better results except the cell on changes colors when I hold the cell. I'd like the cells background color to flash or highlight quickly on a ***tap*** and not really just if the user holds the cell down.

```
class SlideOutMenuCells: UICollectionViewCell {

    //Setup code...

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if self.isHighlighted {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGreen()
            } else {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.mainGreen()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Neither solution really works as intended. I've seen several posts here that try addressing this but haven't found one with a solution that works really. I would like the cell to flash highlight with a tap, and not just when a user clicks and holds on a cell...

Comment: Can you try changing the contentView's background color?

Comment: @AbhishekHarsha this doesn't work. I've tried it as I saw it in some other solutions but no luck.

Comment: @mufc Please check my answer maybe it will solve your problem.

Comment: You have manage selected item in some where as collection view reuse the cell that might be issue

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and the solution is actually much simpler then the one posted above.

In your view controller, add `collectionView.delaysContentTouches = false`.

And then your other code within the cell was fine as is:

```swift
class SlideOutMenuCells: UICollectionViewCell {

    //Setup code...

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if self.isHighlighted {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            } else {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now that annoying delay is gone!

Answer (score 15):

**Here is working code for highlighting** `UICollectionViewCell` **on tap (swift 4 | swift 5)**

> In your view controller, add `collectionView.delaysContentTouches = false`

```
class StoreCollViewCell:UICollectionViewCell{

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if self.isHighlighted {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            } else {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to indicate selection:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let tapGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTap(recognizer:)))
    tapGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

@objc func didTap(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .began {
        backgroundColor = .red
    }
    if recognizer.state == .ended {
        backgroundColor = .green
    }
}
```

or you can make `extension` for `UICollectionViewCell`

```
extension UICollectionViewCell {
func makeSelectionIndicatable() {
    let tapGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTap(recognizer:)))
    tapGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

@objc private func didTap(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .began {
        backgroundColor = .red
    }
    if recognizer.state == .ended {
        backgroundColor = .green
    }
}
```

}

and after that for any cell at `awakeFromNib()` method you just need to add `makeSelectionIndicatable()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing the color if content view in cell like:

```
class SlideOutMenuCells: UICollectionViewCell {

override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? OLTheme.Colors.Selected_Voucher_Color : UIColor.clear
    }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had only to remove the highlight on the collectionViews when tapped.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
         guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: IDSActionList.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? IDSActionList else {
              return
     }
    
         cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
         self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```